# Subgroup of $S_n$ with maximal proportion of derangements

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Consider a subgroup $G$ of $S_n$. I'm interested about the proportion of derangements (permutations with no fixing point) in $G$. For example, the cyclic group $C_n$ has $n-1$ derangements and thus have a $\frac{n-1}{n}$ fraction of derangements; and also as a classic result, $S_n$ has about $1/e$ fraction of derangements. My question is, which subgroup of $S_n$ has the maximal proportion of derangements? In particular, can we beat $\frac{n-1}{n}$?

Comment: Yes, I meant proportion. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Can one computationally (using GAP for instance) decide the answer for several small $n$, as a guide to intuition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) says that the average number of points fixed by an element of $G$ is the number of orbits of $G$, which must be at least $1$.

Since each element of $G$ fixes at most $n$ points, the proportion of elements of $G$ that fix a point must be at least $\frac 1n$. Hence the proportion of elements of $G$ that are derangements is at most $1 - \frac 1n = \frac{n-1}n$.

In order to achieve this bound $G$ must have only one orbit, and the identity must be the only element of $G$ that fixes a point, so the order of $G$ must be $n$. Conversely, every transitive subgroup of order $n$ achieves the bound.